# Set minimum order amount in WooCommerce by user role and order history

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, orders

I'm using a snippet code from WooCommerce [Minimum Order Amount](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/minimum-order-amount/) to set a minimum order total by user role.

For the distributors role, I want to change the minimum order total if they have previous order completed.

So for the first order, the minimum would be 3000, for the orders afterward the minimum would become 1000.

Here is my code:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_check_cart_items', 'wc_minimum_order_amount' );
function wc_minimum_order_amount() {
    // minimum order value by user role
    if ( current_user_can('distributors') )
        $minimum = 3000; 
    elseif ( current_user_can('wholesale_customer') )
        $minimum = 200;
    elseif ( current_user_can('wholesale_vat_exc') )
        $minimum = 200;
    else 
        $minimum = 200; // default

    if ( WC()->cart->subtotal < $minimum ) {

        if( is_cart() ) {
            wc_print_notice( sprintf( 
                'You must have an order with a minimum of %s to place your order, your current order total is %s.' , 
                wc_price( $minimum ), 
                wc_price( WC()->cart->subtotal )
            ), 'error' );
        } else {
            wc_add_notice( sprintf( 
                'You must have an order with a minimum of %s to place your order, your current order total is %s.' , 
                wc_price( $minimum ), 
                wc_price( WC()->cart->subtotal )
            ), 'error' );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the minimum order total for the distributors role based on previous completed orders, you can extend this if condition:

```php
 if ( current_user_can('distributors') )
```

Where you will count the number of previous orders based on the `user_id` and status `wc-completed`, if the count is greater than 0, change the mimimun

---

[wc_get_orders()](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_orders-and-WC_Order_Query) is used for this, this can be further expanded with additional parameters such as certain order statuses, etc.

So you get:

```php
function action_woocommerce_check_cart_items() {
    // minimum order value by user role
    if ( current_user_can( 'distributors' ) ) {         
        // Get completed orders by customer id
        $completed_orders_by_customer_id = wc_get_orders( array(
            'customer_id' => get_current_user_id(),
            'status' => array( 'wc-completed' ),
        ));

        // Number of previous completed orders is greater than 0
        if ( sizeof( $completed_orders_by_customer_id ) > 0 ) {
            $minimum = 1000;
        } else {
            $minimum = 3000; 
        }
    } elseif ( current_user_can( 'wholesale_customer' ) ) {
        $minimum = 200;
    } elseif ( current_user_can( 'wholesale_vat_exc' ) ) {
        $minimum = 200;
    } else { 
        $minimum = 200; // default
    }

    if ( WC()->cart->subtotal < $minimum ) {

        if ( is_cart() ) {
            wc_print_notice( sprintf( 
                'You must have an order with a minimum of %s to place your order, your current order total is %s.' , 
                wc_price( $minimum ), 
                wc_price( WC()->cart->subtotal )
            ), 'error' );
        } else {
            wc_add_notice( sprintf( 
                'You must have an order with a minimum of %s to place your order, your current order total is %s.' , 
                wc_price( $minimum ), 
                wc_price( WC()->cart->subtotal )
            ), 'error' );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_check_cart_items' , 'action_woocommerce_check_cart_items', 10, 0 );
```